# how is it possible to remove variable residual?

Tags: java, algorithm

Cant find solution in the next educational example in JAVA for beginners. Code works, but it can be solved without variable.

```
public static int[] change(int money, int price) {
    int[] coins = {10, 5, 2, 1};
    int[] rsl = new int[100];
    int size = 0;
    int residual = money - price;
    for (int coin : coins) {
        while (residual >= coin) {
            residual = residual - coin;
            rsl[size] = coin;
            size++;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(rsl, size);
}
```

Comment: Which author, and what page?

Comment: trivially you can just remove `residual` and mess with `money` instead - you don't need that variable's value to survive. So just `money -= price;` instead of `int residual = money - price;`, and `price -= coin;` instead of `residual = residual - coin'` (`x -= y` is short for `x = x - y`). Your question is too vague however; I have no idea if this is what you're looking for. VTC.

Comment: Thank you @rzwitserloot! Right code for me was:
public static int[] change(int money, int price) {
        int[] coins = {10, 5, 2, 1};
        int[] rsl = new int[100];
        int size = 0;
        money -= price;
        for (int coin : coins) {
            while (money >= coin) {
                money -= coin;
                rsl[size] = coin;
                size++;
            }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(rsl, size);
    }

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :D
Which variable do you want to get rid of? Or is the task just to get rid of ANY var?

Comment: The right code optimization was in the last comment before you. Now it looks simple )